# How to add and retrive firestore data in list array?

Tags: flutter

How can we store data in a list without using Stream Builder from fire store?

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: i dont understand how to add code in stackoverflow ,it show me error

Comment: Edit the question, then paste your code, only the needed code to recreate / test  issue

Comment: it show me error like this                                                                                 
     Please add some context to explain the code sections (or check that you have not incorrectly formatted all of your question as code).   i

Comment: besides the code, you should add some descriptions.